# In Omnet++, in mingwenv.cmd error as Error: NED type `wireless1.Wireless1' could not be fully resolved, due to a missing base type or interface

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to run the project using the mingwenv.cmd. When I type the command to run my project wireless1 it is showing the following error- Error: NED type `wireless1.Wireless1' could not be fully resolved, due to a missing base type or interface. Can anyone please tell me what this error is about and how should I deal with this error?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your simulation cannot see the type "wireless1.Wireless1" most likely because the corresponding NED files were not found. I suspect you are using INET so I would suggest to start experimenting with the examples and once you can run and modify them move creating your own. Also using the IDE would make sense until you can get a hold how to start from the command line.